# Android hide EditText when webView scrolled

Tags: android, webview, scroll, android-edittext

I have a app which has a browser in it. I am using a EditText as my address bar to type the URL. I need to hide this when the user navigates down the webPage.Like how it happens in the android(default) browser.Please tell me how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class Web_browser extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button go;
    EditText webname;
    SharedPreferences webpref;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_go);
        webname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_web_name);

        go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       webpref=Web_browser.this.getSharedPreferences("web_name",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                //webpref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor webnam =webpref.edit();
                webnam.putString("web", webname.getText().toString());
                webnam.commit();
                Intent intent =new Intent(Web_browser.this,Webveiw.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect the change in Scroll in

```
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
//code for detecting change in scroll goes here

//if satisfied with the level of scroll

editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Toggle the visibilty of editText between different scrollview levels..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should we add any Listener for this?

Comment: I tried it. But the method is not getting triggered(called). Should I add a listener to it?